# Describe how you communicate with an external peripheral device on the I2C bus

Tags: i2c

I am trying to summaraize the general description and can't come up with a way to say it. Describe how you communicate with an external peripheral device on the I2C bus? Maybe with steps

Answer (score 0):

There is plenty of material available throughout the web. For example you will find good information on https://i2c.info/. Also if you look out for data sheets of micro controllers like the [ATMega328p](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjWoqKti6HoAhXuy6YKHWeECI4QFjAAegQIBBAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fww1.microchip.com%2Fdownloads%2Fen%2FDeviceDoc%2FAtmel-7810-Automotive-Microcontrollers-ATmega328P_Datasheet.pdf&usg=AOvVaw0Y4fn4dK3DhHYxt3yx6ySr) you can also find very detailed descriptions.

The usual procedure looks like this:

- Master Setup START condition (HIGH to LOW transition of SDA while SCL is HIGH)
- Master sends I2C device address (usually a 7 bit address + bit0 = 0 to write)
- Slave sends: ACK
- Master sends I2C register address that you want to read (8 bits)
- Slave sends: ACK
- Master sends Repeated START (HIGH to LOW transition of SDA while SCL is HIGH)
- Send I2C device address (7 bit address + bit0 = 1 to read)
- Slave sends: ACK
- Slave sends: MSB of the requested register
- Master sends: ACK
- Slave sends: LSB of the requested register (if register address actually contains more than one Byte)
- Master sends: NACK (to inform the Slave that it received all expected data)
- Master sends STOP (a LOW to HIGH transition of SDA while SCL is HIGH)